# JSHint considers a for-in variable 'bad'. What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax, for-loop, jshint

The following code:

```
var things = {'foo':'bar'}
for ( thing in things ) {
  console.log(thing)
}
```

Consistently produces the following error in jshint:

```
Bad for in variable 'thing'.
```

I do not understand what makes the 'thing' variable 'bad' - as you can see, it is not being used anywhere else. What should I do differently to make jshint not consider this to be an error?

Comment: It's global, which is always bad (bad bad bad bad bad). Try `for( var thing in things)`. Don't know if this is the reason for the error though :)

Comment: JSHint wants `for in` variables to be defined in the local scope (i.e. not in an outer function). It's related to this issue: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/329

Comment: Since 'bad' is so vague, I submitted a pull request to jshint so that it explicitly states that the variable is global.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They always are - if they are not declared. Try adding `var` if `thing` has not been previously declared.

```
for ( var thing in things ) {
  console.log(thing)
}
```

or

```
var thing;

//more code

for ( thing in things ) {
  console.log(thing)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish jshint would say 'Undeclared variable' rather than 'Bad variable' - it would be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code slightly modified, make sure all is declared before usage.

```
var things = {'foo':'bar'}, thing;
for ( thing in things ) {
  console.log(thing)
}
```